# C++ concept for compound assignment operators

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

I have a concept for normal binary operators

```
template<typename Op, typename T> concept is_binary_operation =
    requires (const T& t1, const T& t2) // e.g. a+b
{
    {Op()(t1,t2)}->std::convertible_to<T>;
};
```

and a concept for compound assignment operators

```
template<typename Op, typename T> concept is_operation_and_assign =
   requires (T& t1, const T& t2) // e.g a += b;
{
  {Op()(t1,t2)}->std::convertible_to<T>;
};
```

For compound assignment operators this works as expected:

```
template<typename T> struct op_and_assign
{
    T& operator()(T& t1, const T& t2)
    {
        t1 += t2;
        return t1;
    }
};
```

This "is_operation_and_assign" but not "is_binary_operation"

```
std::cout << is_binary_operation<op_and_assign<double>, double> << " ";
std::cout << is_operation_and_assign<op_and_assign<double>, double> << std::endl;
```

prints "0 1". std::plus, however, satisfies both concepts:

```
std::cout << is_binary_operation<std::plus<double>, double> << " ";
std::cout << is_operation_and_assign<std::plus<double>, double> << std::endl;
```

prints "1 1".

How do I have to change the concept "is_operation_and_assign" so that I get the output "1 0", i.e. so that it will fulfilled by op_and_assign but not by std::plus?

To make more clear what I need: I have two versions of an algorithm, one using the compound assignment operator, one using the binary operator:

```
template<typename Op, typename T>
int f() requires is_operation_and_assign<Op, T>
{   
    return 0;
}
template<typename Op, typename T>
int f() requires is_binary_operation<Op, T>
{ 
    return 1;
}
```

I can call the version for op_and_assign

```
f<op_and_assign<double>, double>();
```

but the version for std::plus

```
f<std::plus<double>, double>();
```

does not compile. (error: call to 'f' is ambiguous)

**Update**: in the meanwhile I found a workaround:

When I simply add `&& !is_binary_operation<Op, T>` to the first `f`:

```
template<typename Op, typename T>
int f() requires (is_operation_and_assign<Op, T>
               && !is_binary_operation<Op, T>)
{ 
    return 0;
}
template<typename Op, typename T>
int f()  requires is_binary_operation<Op, T> 
{ 
   return 1;
}
```

then the second call is no longer ambiguous, i.e. both

```
f<op_and_assign<double>, double>();
f<std::plus<double>, double>();
```

compile (and choose the desired function).

Comment: On another note, you may be able to simplify your concept usage if you use template template parameters in the definition e.g. `template <template <typename T>  typename op> concept `. Looks awkward to have to write the template type twice when using the concept.

Comment: @Mansoor: it is not equivalent, checking for type seems more natural, `is_binary_operation<std::plus<void>, double>` would also make sense.

Comment: What do you mean _but not by `std::plus`_ actually? You can add two `double`s, how would that not be fulfilled?

Comment: @Barry: I think OP wants to check **signature** of `operator()`.

Answer (score 0):

It's important to clarify what actually your concept is checking, because it's not what you think it is.

This:

```
template<typename Op, typename T> concept is_operation_and_assign =
   requires (T& t1, const T& t2) // e.g a += b;
{
  {Op()(t1,t2)}->std::convertible_to<T>;
};
```

Checks that you can invoke `Op()(t1, t2)` with a `T&` and a `T const&` and that you get something that satisfies `convertible_to<T>`. When you provide:

```
template<typename T> struct op_and_assign
{
    T& operator()(T& t1, const T& t2)
    {
        t1 += t2;
        return t1;
    }
};
```

as the first template parameter, what does that actually check? This is an unevaluated expression, we're checking to see if we can invoke `op_and_assign<T>()`. We're not evaluating the body of the call operator, we're just checking to see if it's a valid call. So it's no different than if we wrote:

```
template<typename T> struct op_and_assign
{
    T& operator()(T& t1, const T& t2);
};
```

It's unevaluated, there's no body, so the only things that matter are constraints. Here, there are no constraints, so `op_and_assign` is always invokable as long as the arguments are convertible.

When you do this:

```
is_binary_operation<op_and_assign<double>, double>
```

You're effectively asking if you can convert the arguments appropriately. For `is_binary_operation`, you're providing two arguments of type `double const&` (from your requires expression) but `op_and_assign<double>` needs to take one `double&`. That's why this particular check doesn't work.

---

For how to fix it. `op_and_assign` which should probably look something like this:

```
struct op_and_assign
{
    template <typename T, typename U>
    auto operator()(T&& t, U&& u) const -> decltype(t += u);
};
```

Now we're actually checking if we can perform `+=`.

But that won't change that you can't assign to a `double const&`. You're getting the correct answer there, even if you weren't doing the check you intended to.

Comment: struct op_and_assign does not check anything; it is a function object like std::plus. You can also ask the question in a different way: How can I write 2 concepts that distinguish between op_and_assign and std::plus?

Comment: @Helmut I don't understand what you're asking. You're already distinguishing between them. Distinguish how?

Comment: The problem is that is_binary_operation ist true for op_and_assign and for std::plus. In the example above the compiler says that the call to f ist ambiguous.

Comment: @HelmutZeisel What? `is_binary_operation<op_and_assign<double>, double>` is definitely false.

Comment: @HelmutZeisel And of course the call to `f` is ambiguous, both constraints hold. What's the distinction you're trying to make here? `plus<double>` is invocable with both a const lvalue and a non-const lvalue...

Comment: @HelmutZeisel What is the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: I have two versions of an algorithm, one using the compound assignment operator, one using the binary operator. The version for compound assignment operator is usually faster for data types that have a compound assignment operator. I want that the compiler selects the version for compound assignment operator for data types that have a compound assignment operator, otherwises the compiler should select the version for the binary operator.